# Google reCAPTCHA + AngularJS + Twitter Bootstrap - Modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, recaptcha

I am using google reCAPTCHA through [angular-no-captcha](https://github.com/CodeDistillery/angular-no-captcha) inside a twitter bootstrap modal. Every time the popup is opened, I am required to reset the captcha widget. So I am resetting it, every time modal show event is called as bellow:

```
element.find(".modal").on("show.bs.modal",function(){
  $scope.noCaptchaControl.reset();
});
```

But I get the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined
www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/rpc/rpc.v.js:29
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What is there in rpc.v.js at line no 29 ?

Comment: }}gadgets.config.register("rpc",null,g); ........ Its a minified file

Comment: Use non-minified file here and check which is the exact line where execution stop.Here by seeing error can say that your gadgets.config is undefined.

Comment: This file is an inclusion in https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit so I can not alter it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are missing 'widgetId'

try using through directive

https://github.com/vividcortex/angular-recaptcha

I have implemented recaptcha through this directive .

I have added following code into my html page

```
 <div vc-recaptcha key="'6Le4sgITAAAAAIzD0brQ3-8ikkN1NQStppnsB1Vi'"  on-create="captchaCreate()"

on-success="setResponse(response)"> </div>
               <div ng-show="invalidCaptcha" class="form-group">
                 <div class="has-error">
                       <span class="help-block">Please verify captcha</span>
                         </div>
         </div>
```

and in controller.js

```
$scope.captchaCreate = function() {
                console.log("CREATED");
//                 vcRecaptchaService.reload();
            };

            $scope.invalidCaptcha = false;

            $scope.setResponse = function(response) {
                $scope.user.captcharesponse = response;
                if (response !== null && response !== undefined && response !== '') {
                    $scope.invalidCaptcha = false;
                }
            };


 $scope.resetCaptcha=function(){
 vcRecaptchaService.reload();
};
```

also I have added recaptcha js in script tag and vcRecaptcha module into my app by editing following line

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['vcRecaptcha']);
```

And it works fine for me

Comment: Pls share a demo. I doubt if it supports the new Google noCAPTCHA reCAPTCHA

Comment: I tried implementing angular-recaptcha and calling vcRecaptchaService.reload($scope.widgetId); this too cause the same issue as mentioned in Question

Comment: do you have multiple recaptcha? If not then no need to call  vcRecaptchaService.reload($scope.widgetId); You just need to call vcRecaptchaService.reload(); i.e without passing parameter 'widgetId ' also it will work.. I have implemented it in my system

Comment: I call reload function every time I open the popup and I get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined

Comment: do not calling reload() function on modal open then is it work or gives error, if error then post that error in comment

Comment: There is no error if I do not reload on modal open.. but I need to load fresh captcha every time modal is opened

Comment: Finally it works if I call reload without widget id. Thank you so much!

Comment: I still sometime see, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined error